# Assign a defined variable in a while loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to assign a variable which I've already defined to another one in a while loop but I get this error "(variable name) cannot be resolved to a variable".
I've indicated where I get error using the line numbers of 29,30,32,33.
Java complains by underlining (max) value and (min) value ,which were defined before outside of the while loop, in those lines.
I appreciate any help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {

public static void main (String[] args ) {

    System.out.println("Please number : ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    Scanner in1 = new Scanner (System.in);
    double input = in1.nextDouble();
    double input1  = in1.nextDouble();
    if(input1 > input) {
        double max = input1;
        double min = input ;
    }
    else {
         double max = input ;
        double  min = input1;

    }

    int count = 0;
    double total = 0 ;


    while (in.hasNextDouble())
    {
    double input3 = in.nextDouble();
29-     if (input3 > max) {
30-      max = input3;
    }
32-     if (input3< min) {
33-      min= input3;
    }
    total = total +input3 + input + input1;
    count++;


    }
    double average = 0;
    if(count > 0) {
        average = total /count ;
    }
    System.out.println(average);


}
}
```

Comment: You must understand that declaring a variables inside of a scope are only available of use inside that scope.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables `min` and `max` are defined with **block** level scope. Move the declarations to before the `if` / `else`. Like,

```
double max, min;
if(input1 > input) {
    max = input1;
    min = input;
} else {
    max = input;
    min = input1;
}
```

**or**

```
double max = Math.max(input1, input);
double min = Math.min(input1, input);
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Actually the problem is that I'm not trying to compare two inputs and give the values to variables "max" and "min" but I want to compare an input inside the while loop with variables "max" and "min" . Those 2 variables (max and min) have already  been assigned to 2 other inputs outside of the while loop but it seems when they enter the while loop cannot be recognized and they're assumed as new variables and I've no way to redefine them. Thanks

Comment: @saman You have to declare them outside of the if statement blocks, so that they are within scope of both the if, else and while blocks

Answer (score 0):

When you declare variables with a method or code block, they are limited in scope to that code block, so

```
{
    double max = input1;
    double min = input ;
}
```

means that `max` and `min` are limited in scope to this code block.

Declare them before this code block (same as `input` and `input1`).

And then you can use as

```
double max = 0.00;
double min = 0.00;
if(input1 > input) {
    max = input1;
    min = input ;
 }
 else {
     max = input ;
     min = input1;
}
```